# Printing out std::map

Tags: c++, containers, std

I'm trying to print out the keys and their values from map. 
I don't know what is missing, since I don't get any output in console - hence, something has to be wrong.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <map> 

using namespace std; 

typedef map<string, int> employees; 


int main(void)
{
   employees object;  
   employees ref; 
   employees &m = ref; 
   employees::const_iterator it; 

   object["GREG"] = 1000;  
   object["ROBERT"] = 2000;  

    for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << "Key" << it->first << "Key value: " << it->second << endl; 
    }
}
```

I guess that I've might messed up with the reference to the MAP called employees, perhaps I should have try this solution (which somehow doesn't work either... but, maybe it's less 'stupid approach'):

```
for(it = employees.begin(), it != employees.end(), ++it)
{ 
   employees::const_iterator it; 
}
```

Comment: Try `ref["GREG"] = 1000; ref["ROBERT"] = 2000;` `

Comment: You need to `#include <string>`.

Comment: You are adding values to the ref, but printing object, which is empty

Comment: It works, I see what I did there. I just overwrote reference, thanks a lot :O)

Comment: @WhiteBear: `m` is a reference, `ref` and `object` are map variables.

Comment: @RafalMielniczuk It's actually exactly vice versa.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ well, yes.. but he got it :)

Answer (score 3):

the map you are iterating over does not contain any elements. 
Your loop is:

```
 for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
```

but the only map that you ever fill is

```
object["GREG"] = 1000;  
object["ROBERT"] = 2000;
```

I don't know why you need the gymnastics with the references, but this code prints the objects in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef map<string, int> employees;


int main(void)
{
  employees object;
  employees::const_iterator it;

  object["GREG"] = 1000;
  object["ROBERT"] = 2000;

  for(it = object.begin(); it != object.end(); ++it)
    {
      cout << "Key " << it->first << " Key value: " << it->second << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the employees to the `object` variable, but dumping out the `ref` variable. It's hard to see what you are trying to do. Why do you need `ref` and `m`?  If you just remove the `ref` and `m` variables and use `object` in the `for()` look then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answers given by others, it's worth to consider using for-range loop:

```
for (const auto &emp : object)
{
    cout << "Key " << emp.first << " Key value: " << emp.second << endl;
}
```